# Cause of disparity between methods of calculation of specific angular momentum?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to numerically solve for the delta-V cost of a transfer between two close elliptic orbits which are inclined relative to each other. The method I'm using essentially calculates the velocity vectors of the initial orbit at one node, the final orbit at the opposing node, and then calculates the transfer orbit from initial flight path angle, initial radius, and final radius.

One key step is to calculate the specific angular momentum vector and eccentricity vector of the transfer orbit, in order to calculate the perifocal-to-inertial direction cosine matrix for the transfer orbit. However, when I calculate the angular momentum vector **h** of the transfer orbit in the inertial frame from the cross product of the position and velocity vectors in the inertial frame, I find significant error (relative error is -3.9521e-8) between the magnitude of this vector and the scalar specific angular momentum calculated earlier in the code.

This is strange to me because that scalar angular momentum is used to calculate the velocity vector. I'm confused as to where the loss of precision is occurring.

I've tried providing inputs with greater precision, specifically the mu value I have been using, but this did not shift the relative error at all. When I use the same cross product method to calculate specific angular momentum of orbits 1 and 2, the error is on the order of machine precision.

```
        mu = 3.98600437823e+14;

        thetaNT = -55.1582940061466; % deg
        eT = 0.022905923178296;
        aT = 7.243582592195826e+06; % m

        r1A = 7.146263097977215e+06; % m
        v1RA = -1.390985544431790e+02; % m/s
        v1ThetaA = 7.494958913236144e+03; % m/s

        eR1 = [0.355828643065080;-0.934551216774375;0];
        eTheta1 = [0.934551216774375;0.355828643065080;0];

        nCpf1 = [0.263190394679355,-0.840751409136755,0.473146789255815;
            0.880932410956014,0.00949753358184791,-0.473146789255815;
            0.393305102275257,0.541338032000730,0.743144825477394];
        nCpf2 = [0.107314578042381,-0.875080710676727,0.471929370924401;
            0.879361618777851,-0.137938482815824,-0.455736896003458;
            0.463903788257849,0.463903788257849,0.754709580222772];


        v1A = sqrt(v1RA^2 + v1ThetaA^2); % Total speed of orbit 1 at A

        hT = sqrt(aT*mu*(1-eT^2)); % Specific angular momentum of transfer orbit

        eRTB = [-cosd(thetaNT);sind(thetaNT+180);0];
        eThetaTB = [-sind(thetaNT+180);-cosd(thetaNT);0];

        % Calculation of radial speed and tangential speed
        vTRA = mu/hT*eT*sind(thetaNT);
        vTThetaA = mu/hT*(1+eT*cosd(thetaNT));

        vTA = sqrt(vTRA^2+vTThetaA^2);

        vTRB = mu/hT*eT*sind(thetaNT+180);
        vTThetaB = mu/hT*(1-eT*cosd(thetaNT));

        % Conversion of radius and speeds into radius and velocity vectors
        % in perifocal frames
        r1APF1 = r1A.*eR1;
        v1APF1 = v1RA.*eR1 + v1ThetaA.*eTheta1;

        vTBPFT = vTRB.*eRTB + vTThetaB.*eThetaTB;

        v2BPF2 = v2RB.*eR2 + v2ThetaB.*eTheta2;

        % Conversion to inertial reference frame
        r1AN = nCpf1*r1APF1;
        v1AN = nCpf1*v1APF1;

        v2BN = nCpf2*v2BPF2;

        rTAN = r1AN;
        vTAN = v1AN.*(vTA/v1A);

        % Calculation of angular momentum and eccentricity vectors in
        % inertial frame
        hTN = cross(rTAN, vTAN);
        eTN = cross(vTAN, hTN)./mu - rTAN./norm(rTAN);
        diffh = (norm(hTN)-hT)/hT
        diffe = (norm(eTN)-eT)/eT
```

I would expect diffh and diffe to be on the order of machine precision, roughly 2.2e-16, but they are much greater. Specifically, diffh = -3.9689e-08, and diffe = 7.5474e-05.

UPDATE: The error appears to be appearing somewhere in my calculation of the radial and velocity vectors, if that helps with concentrating your search.

Comment: I can't run your code. I get the error `Undefined function or variable 'v2RB'`.

Comment: Sorry about that, delete the lines `v2BPF2 = v2RB.*eR2 + v2ThetaB.*eTheta2;` and `v2BN = nCpf2*v2BPF2;` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Machine precision is *relative*, it consists of the distance between floating point numbers at a given exponent. In Matlab for example, you can check the machine precision for a given number:

```
eps(1)
  ans = 
        2.22044604049250313e-16
eps(12345)
  ans = 
        1.818989403545856e-12.
```

Usually, you should expect something around `e-16` times the value you are working with. So `1e-8` is in the order of magnitude of the machine precision for the  product of position (order of `1e6`) and velocity (order of `1e2`). I.e. the product should be in the order of `1e8` hence its machine precision is in the order of 8-16=-8.

Also note that if you concerned about accuracy, you might consider using angles in radians rather than degrees.

Comment: To be clear, diff is returning a relative precision. The absolute error at that point is on the order of `1e3`. Also, is there a significant difference in precision in Matlab between degree and radian math? I was under the impression that degree math and radian math worked at the same precision in Matlab, and was using degrees because the raw data I'm working from came in that format.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to assess the relative precision of a cross product like that. The position and velocity should be nearly orthogonal for most of the orbit, and exactly orthogonal at two points in the orbit. Because of that, your relative precision should not use the norm of a cross product `norm(hTN)`, I would rather use `norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN)`.

Comment: Also, if you need to use a lot of raw data in degrees, then I'd suggest sticking to it rather than converting.

Comment: When I used `norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN) - hT` to calculate the error, I got an even worse relative error: `diff = (norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN) - hT)/hT` gives `diff = 1.7216e-04`. I don't think that the approach you suggested will work in this situation.

Comment: Actually, I've meant you should normalize with `norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN)`, that means dividing by it, instead of dividing by `hT`. Hence `diff = (norm(hTN)-hT)/(norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN))`

Comment: Why do you think that would provide a better solution? As the edit to my post indicates, I am fairly certain that the issue lies in my calculation of rTAN and vTAN, since when I proceeded to use them to calculate a different value (eccentricity of the orbit) they also created significant error.

Comment: This should not change the values for rTAN and vTAN, hence this is not meant to provide a better solution. Rather, the suggestion is to maker a better assessment on whether the error you are finding is indeed of numeric nature.

Comment: `diff = (norm(hTN)-hT)/(norm(rTAN)*norm(vTAN))

diff =

  -3.9682e-08
` is the output I got. Is that helpful? It seems to be much the same as the output I was getting previously.

Comment: Yes it is helpful (in a sense). Because, as I've claimed in the original answer, something in the order of `1e-8` is what you should have expected for the numerical accuracy in the first place. You expected `diff` to be in the magnitude of the machine precision and my point is that it indeed is. The bad news for you is that improving accuracy beyond that is far from trivial. In Matlab, I'm unaware of any standard method to improve precision of the default double format, but you might consider rewriting your code in python and use some arbitrary precision library e.g. http://mpmath.org/

Comment: I thought that machine precision in MATLAB was a relative error of `1e-16`? Since diff is relative error, shouldn't it be in that neighborhood, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you compute `100000001.0-100000000.0`, you get `1.0`. but actually, this `1.0` should have precision in the order of `1e-8` and it won't matter if you normalize by 1.0 now. Note that 100000000.0=`1e8`. I believe this is what happens when you compute the cross product: An error of large magnitude appears with the summing operations, because the result is small compared to the summands.

Answer (score 0):

> I calculate the angular momentum vector h of the transfer orbit in the inertial frame from the cross product of the position and velocity vectors in the inertial frame

This is where the error is most likely laying. I do not follow the math you use since I approach these problems differently. I would find the orbital elements of your transfer orbit and then the position of your satellite in your transfer orbit as true anomalies and then calculating the delta V should be fairly trivial since you know your velocity vectors at each time step pre and post burn. If you need me to expand on this let me know where I can clarify and I will.